# How to assign users to a native Azure AD App using Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created an app that uses AAD to authenticate with AAD using ADAL, however after reading this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/845293/how-to-assign-users-to-a-native-app-in-azure-ad) it seems its only possible to assign users to this app using CMDlets and no UI available? is this really true?

Answer (score 1):

You'r right, you can only use cmdlets to assign users to **Native App in AAD v1 endpoint**.

This is because that **Native client** registrations are **multi-tenant** by default. You don’t need to take any action to make a native client application registration multi-tenant. It means that you can sign in this application with any Users in Azure AD with some configuration. So, you wouldn't see Users and Groups in Native client in Enterprise Applications.

However,you can still assign the users **(without roles)** to native applications by using cmdlets in PowerShell.

Comment: Will I be able to see them in the UI after I assign them using cmdlets?

Comment: You can see `Total users` which including users you assigned in the portal. But you cannot see the `Users and Groups` tab.

Comment: Got it I hope this is on the roadmap for fixing to make it easier to work with native mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

You can assign users in the portal.

You need to find your app's *service principal* from Enterprise applications or the "Managed app in local directory" on the App Registration blade.

From there you should find the Users & Groups tab, where you can assign users.

Comment: That users and groups is only available for WEB / API apps not available for Native Apps as far I can see, you can see the print screen on the link in my question as well it looks identical to mine

Comment: Oh that's pretty weird.. I was not aware of this problem with native apps. In that case PowerShell or the Graph API would be your only choices.

Comment: Yeah powershell works I just find it unbelievable that it cannot be done from the Azure Portal, I must be missing something simple here I feel.

Comment: If PS works, then this is basically a missing feature in my opinion.

Comment: You can't assign users or groups to a Native (Public) app as such app doesn't have roles. The only way to do it is using Powershell: 
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id ([Guid]::Empty)